# iPhoneX and iPhone 8 keyboard height are different

Tags: ios, iphone-x

I use below code to get keyboard height. Then use this height to calculate the frame of an `UIView` to make sure this `UIView` just on the top of the keyboard.

But in iPhoneX simulator the output is `333` and the iPhone 8 simulator is `258`.

**ISSUE**: If use `rect.height` as the keyboard height for iPhone 8 simulator then the layout is correct. For iPhone X there's a gap between the `UIView` and keyboard. Which means `333` is higher than the real keyboard height in iPhone X.

What's the reason of the height are different? And how to get the correct keyboard height?

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)


@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        if let rect = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
           print(rect.height)
        } 
    }
```

Like this image, the green border should be the extra part. Actually, I need the red part just on the top of keyboard without the green rect gap.
[image]

**EDIT**

OK, with @Craig's help I found this method only called by iPhone X. So I update frame here. Just paste the code here.

The safe area bottom height is 22.0 seems not correct.

```
override func viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        super.viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()
        view.safeAreaInsets.bottom // This value is the bottom safe area place value.
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**
Normally `view.safeAreaInsets.bottom` should be 34.0, but if you are using container view this value can be different like mine is 22.0.

Comment: what is your issue actually? you ask for an opinion-based speculation in your question.

Comment: You can always use `rect.height` to calculate what's remaining?

Comment: @holex I edited my question. My question is i can't get correct keyboard height by ```rect.height``` from the notification.

Comment: @zcui93 ```rect.height``` should be the keyboard height normally.

Comment: @zcui93 You are right, i think for iPhone X the rect height isn't keyboard height anymore. Should plus the bottom part.

Comment: I was using `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` instead of `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`. This gave me different height values  on consecutive keyboard toggles. But the first key was working on non-iPhone-X just fine.... strange

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The keyboard height for both iPhone X and iPhone 8 should be correct. I can only guess that maybe you have a problem in your code for locating the "red part", and your assumption was that the keyboard height was incorrect whereas the problem was actually in the *location* of the view. Now - the reason for the location problem? My second guess is the red part is pinned to the bottom safe area layout guide, which on the iPhone 8 is 0, but on the iPhone X is inset 34 points.

See this image to illustrate both the difference in keyboard heights and that it is possible to draw a rectangle just above the keyboard using the keyboard height from the keyboard height reported in the `NSNotification` for the `keyboardWillShow` method:

[image]

If you want to share your code / constraints for positioning the red view, I should be able to show you the problem.

**--Edit:** For anyone interested to know how I extract the drew the red rectangle, I go into it in a blog post [here](https://craiggrummitt.com/2019/02/22/getting-the-keyboard-height/).

Comment: Yeah, i think you are right. "The inset is 34 pt", i tried ```view.safeAreaInset``` in both iPhone 8 and iPhone X seems all (0,0,0,0), how to get this value?

Comment: If you tried it in `viewDidLoad`, it seems as though this value isn't yet set at this point. You can override `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange` to see this value: `override func viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
  print(view.safeAreaInsets)
}`

Answer (score 48):

While [Craig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46423340/7698127) is correct, you might not want to pin your view to  *view.bottom* or the *bottomLayoutGuide* rather than the *safe area bottom* (especially if your keyboard is not always open, and you don't want your views to cover the Home Indicator area).

Here is a fix for these cases. It deducts the height of the bottom inset of the safe area from the height of the keyboard:

```
var keyboardHeight = ... // Get the keyboard height from keyboard notification

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    let bottomInset = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    keyboardHeight -= bottomInset
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for every device and iOS version so far

```
- (void)keyboardWillShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
        NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
        CGFloat kbHeight = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;
        CGFloat safeAreaBottomInset = 0;
        if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
            safeAreaBottomInset = self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
        }
        self.containerViewBottomConstraint.constant += (kbHeight - safeAreaBottomInset); //In my case I use a constraint to adapt the UI when the keyboard is presented
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: Just pin to Superview.Bottom constraint.  Not safe area.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem. What I did, simply I check keyboard that is different on iPhone 7 and iPhone X. I just add some default margin with keyboard height. Now It is working fine on every device.

Comment: Adding magic fixed numbers should NEVER be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
//Here keyboard is without any toolbar and suggestions boxes
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let keyboardHeight = ((keyboardSize.height) > 240) ? 220 :  (keyboardSize.height - 47)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}
```

Comment: Using magic number like that is NOT pretty. What happends when Apple decides to change the height of i.e. the home bar? They have done so before...

Answer (score 0):

It can get tricky if your view is embedded as a child view (like TabBar or PagerViewController) and you don't have access to the parent (if you're a framework for example).

This can be also calculated by the diff of current view height with the window height and the Y position of the current view:

#### Swift:

```
func calculateHeightOffsetFromContainer() -> CGFloat {
    let convertedYInParent = self.view.convert(self.view.frame, to: nil).origin.y
    let offsetInViewHeights = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - self.view.frame.height
    return offsetInViewHeights - convertedYInParent;
}
```

Usage:

```
let keyboardYPosition = keyboardFrame.height - offsetFromConteiner
```

#### Objective C:

```
- (CGFloat)calculateHeightOffsetFromContainer {
    CGFloat convertedYInParent = [self.view convertRect: self.view.frame toView: nil].origin.y;
    CGFloat offsetInViewHeights = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - self.view.frame.size.height;
    return offsetInViewHeights - convertedYInParent;
}
```

Usage:

```
CGFloat keyboardYPosition = keyboardFrame.size.height - offsetFromConteiner;
```